# Pushing RTMP Stream to multiple dynamic destination

Tags: php, nginx, rtmp

I have a application that works like a RTMP proxy server.

```
rtmp {
    server{
         listen 1935;
         chunk_size 4096;
    
         application live {
             live on;
             record off;
        
             push rtmp://server1/live/{key1}
             push rtmp://server2/live/{key2}
         }
    }
}
```

The **key1** and **key2** coming from a PHP file.
How can i replace keys from PHP file to nginx config file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process the stream, it's a powerful pattern to use FFmpeg to pull and push as different streams:

```sh
ffmpeg -f flv -i rtmp://localhost:1935/app/bbbb \
  -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/app/aaaaaa \
  -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/app/cccccc
```

> Note: You could use the `on_publish` hook to start your FFmpeg process, or `exec` should also works. However it's a bit complex for introducing FFmpeg.

If you want to use `push` feature, it's a complex and dynamic `forwarding`, I think it's very hard to support it because it depends on our use scenarios, which is very different and not common to everyone.

> Note: However, I think the best solution is like `http hooks forwarding`, that is call your backend and get the streams to forward to. Here is a [discuss](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/issues/1342#issuecomment-997851990) about dynamic forwarding by http hooks.

Comment: I read the whole discuss but did not understand anything.

Comment: Also  `forward { backend http://127.0.0.1:8085/api/v1/forward; }` throw me error. `Failed, code=1023 : check config : check normal : illegal vhost.forward.backend of __defaultVhost__`

Comment: Sorry, there is a english wiki for dynamic forward https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/forward#dynamic-forward